# APNS using ASP .net server in the backgorund

Tags: asp.net, ios6, apple-push-notifications

I am new to implement Push notification services. I am implementing an application with push notification services. At the server end we are using .net coding and using moon app code to send notifications to devices. My problem is i am getting notifications when we use developer certificate (p12 file) when we host it I am unable to get the deivces. We also tested this with production (p12 file) certificate. Event though I am not getting the notifications. Can you guys suggest me the flow implementation and requirement that we need before hosting it.

Thank you,
Sekhar.

Comment: Have you followed the instructions in the [Apple Developer Guide to Local and Push Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG) in particular the seconds titled "Provisioning and Deployment" and "Provider Communication with Apple Push Notification Service"?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure below step is correct.

```
var push = new PushNotification(false, "p12 file location","password");
                               //true-sandbox and false-production.
```

If not above then something wrong in Ur p12 certification.